# Cluster of two different machine with high availability?

Tags: hazelcast, high-availability, vert.x

I have two different machine. One is configured with IP 192.168.2.100 and the other one with 192.168.2.101.
This is the code of the first verticle :

```
 public class Sender extends AbstractVerticle {

public static void main(String... args) {

        // Configuration du cluster manager
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.2.101");

        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
        options.setClusterManager(new HazelcastClusterManager());
        options.setClusterHost("192.168.2.100");
        options.setClustered(true);
        options.setHAEnabled(true);


        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, vertx ->
                vertx.result().deployVerticle(Sender.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setHa(true))
        );
    }


    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        vertx.setPeriodic(5000, id -> {
            vertx.eventBus().send("Address", "message",rep->{
            System.out.println("response : "+rep.result().body());
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the second verticle:

```
 package com.vetx.Consumer;
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;



public class Consumer extends AbstractVerticle {

    private String name = null;

    public Consumer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Consumer(){

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        // Configuration du cluster manager
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.2.100");

        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
        options.setClusterManager(new HazelcastClusterManager());
        options.setClusterHost("192.168.2.101");
        options.setClustered(true);
        options.setHAEnabled(true);



        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, vertx ->
                vertx.result().deployVerticle(Consumer.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setHa(true))
        );
    }


    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("Address", message -> {
            System.out.println(" received message: " +message.body());
           message.reply("Success");
        });
    }
}
```

I try to use the high availability with cluster to implement a consumer to consume a message and a sender to send the message.When a try to kill the sender in order to redeploy verticle after failover, i got the following exception :

```
    SEVERE: Failed to redeploy verticle after failover
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vetx.Sender.Sender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:37)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:229)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:202)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:76)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:171)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:143)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:131)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.HAManager.doDeployVerticle(HAManager.java:281)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.HAManager.processFailover(HAManager.java:553)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.HAManager.checkFailover(HAManager.java:489)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.HAManager.nodeLeft(HAManager.java:309)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.HAManager.access$100(HAManager.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.HAManager$1.nodeLeft(HAManager.java:152)
    at io.vertx.spi.cluster.hazelcast.HazelcastClusterManager.memberRemoved(HazelcastClusterManager.java:325)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterServiceImpl.dispatchEvent(ClusterServiceImpl.java:916)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterServiceImpl.dispatchEvent(ClusterServiceImpl.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.LocalEventDispatcher.run(LocalEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.process(StripedExecutor.java:217)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the cluster members should have the class `com.vetx.Sender.Sender` in their classpath since it will be serialized/deserialized on both sides. Seems like one of the members doesn't have it. 
Also, did you make sure members can form a cluster of 2? I see your network config has one ip on each host `getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.2.101")`, best practice is to add all ip's on all hosts i.e. to have an identical network config on all hosts to avoid confusions.

Comment: From the console i can see that the members can form a cluster of 2

Comment: But the problem with this solution is when i relaunch the killed node (ip : 192.168.2.100), the redeployed verticle in the other machine keep sending the message. So ,i get a problem of redundance of message

Comment: I'm no Vert.x expert but as I see you're periodically sending a message on the first node, so it's expected, no?